# CloudFormation Template format error: Every Parameters object must contain a Type member

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following very simple CloudFormation template:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: 'EC2 Instance Type'
    Default: t2.micro
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-08589eca6dcc9b39c
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: default
```

On validating this template using:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cloudformation.yml
```

I receive the following cryptic error message:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation:
  Template format error: Every Parameters object must contain a Type member.
```

What does it mean? I googled for this error message and found nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message can be confusing - especially if you have a lot of parameters - and it does not appear to be documented anywhere. It is however mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) in the docs that:

> Each parameter must be assigned a parameter type that is supported by AWS CloudFormation. For more information, see [Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties-type).

Thus to fix this template, just add a type:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Type: String  ## ADD THIS LINE
    Description: 'EC2 Instance Type'
    Default: t2.micro
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-08589eca6dcc9b39c
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: default
```

See also [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678784/validationerror-when-calling-the-createstack-operation-template-format-error) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221323/cloudformation-template-is-invalid-template-format-error-every-outputs-member) here at Stack Overflow.